# Python Requests returning text

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

The query returns the response as text and I would like to get it as json.

Python 3.5.3

```
import ssl
import json
import requests

url = 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/'

payload = json.dumps({'User':'Adam', 'Password':'123456'})

r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

Response:

```
In [23]: r.text

Out[23]: 'status=ok&info=00005'

In [24]: r.json()

Out[24]: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

How to get this data in json format like this:

```
{
'status: 'ok',
'info': '00005'
}
```

Comment: Presumably you control the server application if its running on localhost, so why aren't you just returning JSON?

Comment: check here http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: Server address is a example i do not control them. Server return header link 'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given text is not a json string, but a query string.

You can use [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) to get a dictionary or [`urllib.parse.parse_qsl`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qsl) to get a list of (key, value) pairs from the query string.

```
>>> urllib.parse.parse_qs('status=ok&info=00005')
{'status': ['ok'], 'info': ['00005']}


>>> urllib.parse.parse_qsl('status=ok&info=00005')
[('status', 'ok'), ('info', '00005')]
>>> dict(urllib.parse.parse_qsl('status=ok&info=00005'))
{'status': 'ok', 'info': '00005'}
```